# Ember Data queryRecord repeats unccesary calls after include parameters

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am querying data from the store with a code akin to this one:

```
options = {
   "include": "from, to"
};


this.get('store').queryRecord('path', options).then( function(paths) {
    ...
  };
});
```

When taking a look at the network calls, the GET **path** successfully resolves including the **from, to** objects in the **included** object of the response.

Right after the network call is performed, two additional GET calls fetching the **from** and **to** objects are also fired, leaving the included objects completely useless.

I have tried removing the included options and application works as expected, leaving the option apparently pointless.

I am using Ember Data version 2.3.0.

Comment: show your server response and your adapter and serializer.

Comment: probably you are trying to resolve one object by its id which was not found previously

Comment: where are you using the from and to objects? If you are trying to use them in some template, for example, that gets loaded before your promise resolves, Ember will try to fetch then individually, because the response didn't return at the time Ember needed their info.

Comment: Thank you luishl, that was the issue.